# Get background-position

Tags: iphone, html, css, webkit

I'm trying to animate a canvas on three different layers on the onmousedown and ontouchstart. The three canvas go from left to right at a different speed to give a perspective effect as long as the onmouseup or ontouchend are not fired.

I am using @-webkit-keyframes css to do my animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes aCarsRight
{
from{background-position: 0px 0px;}
to{background-position: 640px 0px;}
}

.cars_move_right
{
-webkit-animation-name: aCarsRight;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
}
```

What I would like to do is get the current background-position of the three layers prior to disabling the pan animation and set them manually so when I remove the .cars_move_right class from my div is stays in the same position instead of rolling back to its default position.

Is there a way to get the background-position or just a work around to get what I want? The page is meant for iPhone and iPod Touch.

Thanks !

---

I found something interesting. Instead of grabbing the background-position, stop the animation and set the background-position to my divs, I pause the animation.

```
document.getElementById('global').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
document.getElementById('global_cars').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
document.getElementById('global_car').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'paused';
```

Haven't had the chance to test it on iPhone yet.

---

And, here's a method that seems to work cross-browswers to get any property:
    window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('div'))['background-position'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can use this to get the property I couldn't get with [mydiv].style.[property]

```
function getProperty(property, div)
{
    return window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(div))[property];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:
var blah = ele.style.backgroundPosition;

That will return it like "10px 57px"

If the css rule has a hyphen in it then afaik in Javascript the hyphen is removed and camel case applied.

Comment: Yes I tried that already. For some reasons getting background properties (background and backgroundPosition, in fact) doesn't work in all cases, which I've not been able to nail down yet. The getComputedStyle function works great though.